# What does the new operator mean in this code

Tags: c#

I'm newbe C# student, when I studied code-reading I have a problem this code

```cs
public class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] priorities, int location)
    {
        int answer = 0;
        Queue<KeyValuePair<int, int>> que = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < priorities.Length; i++)
        {
            que.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, priorities[i]));
        }
    }
```

As I know the `new` operator operates to create instance in reference type object like this code:

```cs
Queue<KeyValuePair<int, int>> que = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
```

(so `que` is made in stack and `new` allocates memory in heap  <-- I've learnt like this)

but:

```cs
que.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, priorities[i]))
```

In this code `new` acts without variables.

(Ps. I found the KeyValuePair<> is struct type I wonder why value type use "new"... we don't use "new" in value type like `int a= new 3`  )

I want know what happens

plz teach me

thank you

Comment: [new operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)

Comment: `method(new something())` is a shorter (one-liner) version of what you already know with `var a = new somthing(); method(a);`. It's useful if you don't need `a` as it makes code shorter, thus easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `new MyType()` **creates** an instance of `MyType` - that is where memory is allocated.

When you write `MyType m = ...` you just **assign** something to a variable. This does not allocate anything.

So those two expressions are completely independent. You can assign something you didn´t create (directly) before:

```
MyType m = new MyType();
MyType m2 = m; // just re-reference the instance created above, no memory allocation here
```

and you can also create an object and don´t do anything with it (although this is usually a bad idea):

```
new MyType();
```

In the case of `que.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, priorities[i]))` you create a `KeyValuePair`, but assign it to the methods `item`-parameter.

You could also store that object into a new variable and pass that to the method:

```
var kv = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, priorities[i]);
que.Enque(kv);
```

Comment: Thank you your answer but I still have question. Ms Doc explains KeyValuePair is struct type and I know it is value type. so i wonder why "new" is needed. 

we do not use

 int a= new 3

Comment: @박지현 You can usew `new` for value-types as well. However in case of integral types that represent only a single value, there´s not much use for it, which is why there exists no constructor that excapts any value. A `KeyValuePair` however represents twi distict things that needs to be assigned. As both are essential for the instance, you have to provide them with the ctor-args.